# How to reject and HTTP Posts based on content length without parsing the request stream in C#?

Tags: c#, http, post, http-headers, httpwebrequest

Some third party is posting data to our webpage via HTTP Post. I want to set a limit say 1 Kb for HTTP posts, if it is above 1 Kb I need to reject the HTTP post. I don't want to read the whole request stream to find out the content length. Is there anyway I can validate without reading the entire request stream?

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether the content length is in the headers or not. If it is, you can just fetch that (e.g. [`HttpRequest.ContentLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.contentlength.aspx)). However, they don't have to specify that.

Otherwise, you could just read the first 1K and 1 extra byte:

```
 byte[] data = new byte[1025];
 int length = 0;
 using (var stream =  request.GetBufferlessInputSream())
 {
     while (length < validData.Length)
     {
         int bytesRead = stream.Read(data, length, data.Length - length);
         if (bytesRead == 0)
         {
             break;
         }
         length += bytesRead;
     }
 }
 if (length > 1024)
 {
     // Client sent more than 1024 bytes of data!
 }
 // Otherwise, use the first "length" bytes of data
```

Note that `data` has a size of 1025 so that we *try* to read one more byte than we're allowing the client to send.

If the client has sent more than 1K, we'll still read the first 1K - but we'll only read a single unnecessary byte. We won't keep reading forever.